# Pandas: More responsive syntax or function which compares value of a cell in column with previous cell and find custom week and week sequences

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I have created a loop which does the job but is very inefficient in execution.

Example Dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,3],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,2],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,1],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2869,-85],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,5],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,20],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,12],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,13],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,12],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[3048,-75],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1]],
columns=['id','day_delta'])

df
        id  day_delta
    .
    .
    .
    5   2801    0
    6   2801    0
    7   2801    0
    8   2801    0
    9   2801    0
    10  2801    0
    11  2801    0
    12  2801    0
    13  2801    0
    14  2801    0
    15  2801    2
    16  2801    0
    17  2801    0
    18  2801    0
    19  2801    0
    20  2801    1
    21  2801    0
    22  2801    0
    23  2801    0
    24  2869    -85
    25  2869    0
    26  2869    0
    27  2869    1
    28  2869    0
    29  2869    0
    30  2869    0
    31  2869    1
    32  2869    0
    33  2869    0
    .
    .
    .
```

**The code I applied for getting custom workweek:**

```
df['workweek']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
        if i==0:
            df.loc[i,'workweek']=1
        else:
            if df["id"][i]==df["id"][i-1]:
                if df["day_delta"][i-1]>1:
                    df['workweek'][i]=df['workweek'][i-1] + 1
                else:
                    df['workweek'][i]=df['workweek'][i-1]
            else:
                df['workweek'][i]=1
```

**Result_1 :**

```
     id day_delta   workweek
.
.
.
5   2801    0   2
6   2801    0   2
7   2801    0   2
8   2801    0   2
9   2801    0   2
10  2801    0   2
11  2801    0   2
12  2801    0   2
13  2801    0   2
14  2801    0   2
15  2801    2   2
16  2801    0   3
17  2801    0   3
18  2801    0   3
19  2801    0   3
20  2801    1   3
21  2801    0   3
22  2801    0   3
23  2801    0   3
24  2869    -85 1
25  2869    0   1
26  2869    0   1
27  2869    1   1
28  2869    0   1
29  2869    0   1
30  2869    0   1
31  2869    1   1
32  2869    0   1
33  2869    0   1
.
.
.
```

**Code I applied for creating week sequence:**

```
df['week_seq']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
        if i==0:
            df.loc[i,'week_seq']=1
        else:
            if df["workweek"][i]!=df["workweek"][i-1]:
                df['week_seq'][i]=1
            else:
                df['week_seq'][i]=df['week_seq'][i-1]+1
```

Result_2:

```
    id  day_delta   workweek    week_seq
.
.
.
5   2801    0   2   1
6   2801    0   2   2
7   2801    0   2   3
8   2801    0   2   4
9   2801    0   2   5
10  2801    0   2   6
11  2801    0   2   7
12  2801    0   2   8
13  2801    0   2   9
14  2801    0   2   10
15  2801    2   2   11
16  2801    0   3   1
17  2801    0   3   2
18  2801    0   3   3
19  2801    0   3   4
20  2801    1   3   5
21  2801    0   3   6
22  2801    0   3   7
23  2801    0   3   8
24  2869    -85 1   1
25  2869    0   1   2
26  2869    0   1   3
27  2869    1   1   4
28  2869    0   1   5
29  2869    0   1   6
30  2869    0   1   7
31  2869    1   1   8
32  2869    0   1   9
33  2869    0   1   10
.
.
.
```

I am getting the correct result in **column 'workweek' and 'week_seq'**, but the process is highly inefficient over large dataset.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this? Maybe making a function and using apply method to it?

something in this format maybe?:

```
df['col_3'] = df.apply(lambda x: f(x.col_1, x.col_2, x.col_3), axis=1)
```

I am not sure, how to apply this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import time

data = [[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,3],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,2],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,1],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2801,0],[2869,-85],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,5],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,20],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,12],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,13],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,12],[2869,0],[2869,1],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[2869,0],[3048,-75],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,0],[3048,1]]

# reference approach
s = time.time()
df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','day_delta'])
df['workweek']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i==0:
        df.loc[i,'workweek']=1
    else:
        if df["id"][i]==df["id"][i-1]:
            if df["day_delta"][i-1]>1:
                df['workweek'][i]=df['workweek'][i-1] + 1
            else:
                df['workweek'][i]=df['workweek'][i-1]
        else:
            df['workweek'][i]=1
df['week_seq']=0
for i in range(len(df)):
    if i==0:
        df.loc[i,'week_seq']=1
    else:
        if df["workweek"][i]!=df["workweek"][i-1]:
            df['week_seq'][i]=1
        else:
            df['week_seq'][i]=df['week_seq'][i-1]+1
e = time.time()
target_delta = e - s

df_target = df.copy()
del df

# faster approach
def add_cols(df):
    f = lambda g: (g.day_delta.shift(1) > 1).cumsum() + 1
    df['workweek'] = df.groupby('id').apply(f).values
    inner = lambda g: np.array(range(1, len(g) + 1))
    outer = lambda g: g.groupby('workweek').apply(inner)
    df['week_seq'] = np.concatenate(df.groupby('id').apply(outer).values)

s = time.time()
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['id','day_delta'])
add_cols(df)
e = time.time()
faster_delta = e - s

# test
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, df_target)

# runtime
speedup = target_delta / faster_delta
print(f'~{speedup:.2f}x speedup')
```

This seems to be a good deal faster when I run it (typically >5x speedups). But I'm curious as to how this speedup translates to running on more data.

Comment: Thank you. The full data used to take about 40 sec to run using my method. It took 0.9 Sec with yours! Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: thats very nice :D

Comment: Have you also checked the correctness on the larger data? I am fairly sure that it behaves just as the reference implementation you provided, however no guarantees